# Inverse of power-set functor?

Tags: set-theory, category-theory

In his answer to this Q: [How to interpret $1 \to 0$ in $\mathbf {Set^{op}}$, and $\mathbf {Set^{op}}$ itself](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140196/how-to-interpret-1-to-0-in-bf-set-mathrmop-and-bf-set-mathrmop/309969#309969)? Zhen Lin proposed that $\mathbf {Set^{op}}$ is naturally equivalent to the category of complete atomic boolean algebras via the contravariant power set functor.

As a step in understanding this equivalence, what's the inverse of the contravariant set functor?

Comment: The set of atoms?

Comment: Yes, some kind of projection. But what exactly? What are atoms in sets, elements?

Comment: I don't understand the question in your comment.

Comment: Who voted to close, please state your rationale.

Comment: Atoms in a Boolean algebra are elements that minimal non-zero, that is, $a$ is an atom if $a\neq 0$ and if $0\leq b\leq a$ then either $b=0$ or $b=a$.  The atoms in the power set thought of as a Boolean algebra are exactly the singletons, hence Hurkyl's description of the inverse.

Comment: @Shawn: Actually $b$ is an atom if set $\{x\mid x\leq b\}$ is linearly ordered. If you look at power sets then this corresponds to the successors of the minimum, but it doesn't have to generally.

Comment: @Asaf:  Not true: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/atomic+Boolean+algebra

Comment: Okay, maybe I shouldn't say not true, that might be equivalent, but certainly you don't want non-successors:  If $0<x<b$ then $\neg x \wedge b\neq 0$ and $x\vee (\neg x\wedge b)=b$, hence, by your own definition here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110011/an-atom-in-boolean-algebra, x=0 or x=b, contradiction.

Comment: I think that essentially proves the equivalence, too:  If $0<x<b$, then $\neg x\wedge b$ is non-zero, $\leq b$, and incomparable with $x$, so $\{x|x\leq b\}$ is not linearly ordered.  The converse is trivial.

Comment: @Shawn: Hm, I don't know where I saw the definition I use here (although I am starting to recall it was in the context of forcing, and orders before they are embedded into a Boolean algebra); but I gave one of my teachers a call, as his work is in Boolean algebras, he pointed out that it is the same thing from Stone's Representation theorem. Every Boolean algebra is isomorphic to a subalgebra of a power set, so atoms must be singletons - i.e. minimals over zero.

Comment: For the purposes of this question atom definitely means an element that is minimal in the sub-poset excluding the bottom element. The general definition is harder, yes.

Comment: @Asaf Your definition seems much less useful when is also interested in lattices that are not Boolean.

Comment: @ZhenLin, the Wikip. article on [Equivalence of categories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_categories) states that if a functor is an equivalence, then it preserves (and reflects) initial and terminal objects. If so, how is it consistent with the action of the power-set functor on objects,  eg $2^{()}: 0 \mapsto 1$ and $2^{()}: 1 \mapsto 2$.

Comment: $2$ is initial in $\textbf{CABA}$, and $1$ is terminal in $\textbf{CABA}$. No problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalence between $\mathbf{Set}^{op}$ and $\mathbf{CABA}$ is induced by an adjointness between $\mathbf{Set}^{op}$ and $\mathbf{CBA}$, where the latter is the category of complete Boolean algebras (i.e.  without any assumption about atoms).

First a recall the general principle:

Suppose $F: \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{A}$ is left adjoint to $G: \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{X}$ with unit $\eta: Id_{\mathcal{X}} \to GF$ and counit $\varepsilon: FG \to Id_{\mathcal{A}}$.

Then the two full subcategories
$\{ X \in \mathcal{X} \mid \eta_X \text{ is an isomorphism} \}$ and
$\{ A \in \mathcal{A} \mid \varepsilon_A \text{ is an isomorphism} \}$
are equivalent and the equivalences are given by the restrictions of F and G.  (this follows from the triangular equalities).

So now let's proceed to construct such adjoint functors. I will do this with $\mathcal{X}=\mathbf{Set}$ and $\mathcal{A}=\mathbf{CBA}^{op}$, but it is of course only a matter of taste where to put the $op$.  Anyway I will draw the maps in $\mathbf{Set}$ and $\mathbf{CBA}$. The crucial ingredient is the two element set $2 = \{ 0,1 \}$, which is of course a set, but also a complete Boolean algebra under the ordering with $0 < 1$.

Given a set $X$, set $P(X) = \mathbf{Set}(X,2)$.
Given a complete boolean algebra $B$, set  $Q(B) = \mathbf{CBA}(B,2)$.

On morphism $P$ and $Q$ act via precompositon, i.e. for $f: X \to Y$ the map $P(f): P(Y) \to P(X)$ takes $h \in P(Y)$ to $h\circ f \in P(X)$.  Similar for $Q$.

Then that gives two functors $P: \mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{CBA}^{op}$ and $Q: \mathbf{CBA}^{op} \to \mathbf{Set}$.  This is clear for $Q$. For $P$ observe that the power set $P(X)$ is indeed a complete Boolean algebra, regardless of whether you view its elements as subsets of $X$ or as characteristic maps from $X$ to $2$.

For a set $X$ define $\eta_X : X \to Q(P(X)$ via
$\eta_X(x)\sigma := \sigma(x)$ for all $x\in X$, $\sigma\in P(X)$.
This gives the unit of the adjunction: given $f: X \to Q(B)$, the corresponding map $\hat{f}: B \to P(X)$ must satisfy

$$\matrix{
f(x)b = 1 &\iff& (\eta_X(x)\circ \hat{f})b = 1 \cr
          &\iff& \eta_X(x)(\hat{f}b) = 1 \cr
          &\iff& \hat{f}(b)x = 1 \cr
}
$$
and this can be taken to define $\hat{f}$ via $\hat{f}(b)x := f(x)b$.

In particular, for $X=Q(B)$ and $f=id_{Q(B)}$ the counit $\varepsilon_B: B \to P(Q(B))$ is given by $\varepsilon_B(b)h := h(b)$ for all $b \in B$, $h\in Q(X)$.

For a complete Boolean algebra $B$, write $at(B)$ for the set of its atoms and given $b\in B$ write $at(B/b)$ for the atoms below $b$.  No matter what precise definition of 'atom' is used, the only facts to recall are that the meet of two different atoms is the bottom element and that if $B$ is atomic then every $b\in B$ satisfies $b = \bigvee(at(B/b))$.

Now the following steps pin down the full subcategories:

(1) If $B$ is atomic, then every $h\in Q(B)$ is completely determined by its restriction to $at(B)$. Moreover the preimage $h^{-1}(1)$ contains exactly one atom $a_h$ and for each $b \in B$ we have the equivalence 
$h(b)=1 \iff a_h\leq b$.
Conversely, given an $a\in at(B)$, this equivalence defines an element of $Q(B)$.  Therefore the assignment $h \mapsto a_h$ gives a bijection between $Q(B)$ and $at(B)$.

(2) $P(X)$ is always atomic and the atoms are the singleton subsets of $X$.  From (1) we have that for every $h \in Q(P(X))$ there is a unique $x\in X$ such that $h = \eta_X(x)$. In particular $\eta_X$ is always an isomorphism.

(3) If $\varepsilon_B: B\to P(Q(B))$ is an isomorphism then $B$ must be atomic because of (2). Conversely suppose $B$ is atomic. Given $\sigma \in P(Q(B))$, let $S = \sigma^{-1}(1) \subseteq Q(B)$ be the corresponding subset of morphisms from $B$ to $2$.  Set $b = \bigvee \{a_s\mid s \in S \}$. Then
$$\matrix{
\varepsilon_B(b)h = 1 &\iff& h(b) = 1 \cr
                      &\iff& \exists s\in S: h(a_s) = 1 \cr
                      &\iff& \exists s\in S: a_h \leq a_s \cr
                      &\iff& \exists s\in S: a_h = a_s \cr
                      &\iff& h \in S \cr
                      &\iff& \sigma(h) = 1 \cr
}
$$
and this $b$ is the unique $b\in B$ with $\varepsilon_B(b)=\sigma$.
Therefore $\varepsilon_B$ is an isomorphism iff $B$ is atomic.

Comment: Thanks you for the thorough answer. I'm accepting it even if I don't understand many if not most of the details. But I'm interested in this subject so surely I'll ask additional related Q's based on this.